# Getting the height of all children before the current div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a markup like this:

```
<div class="list">
 <div data-id="2741"></div>
 <div data-id="1499"></div>
 <div data-id="5732"></div>
 <div data-id="6372"></div>
 <div data-id="1034"></div>
</div>
```

Then, I have the current ID with:

`var current_id = $(this).attr('data-id');`

What I want to get is the basically if I have `data-id=6372` (second last), the height of all the divs `BEFORE` that ID, but not after.

How do I achieve that?

Comment: Get the parent's bounding box top, get the current element's bounding box top, and subtract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it, I'm not an expert, I suppose you already have current `data-id`, so I assign one `data-id` randomly

```js
var current_id = 5732,
    divs = [],
    aux = true;

$("div[data-id='"+current_id+"']").parent().children().each( function (){
  if (aux) {
    divs.push($(this).attr("data-id"));
    aux = $(this).attr("data-id") == current_id ? false : aux;
  }
});

for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
  $("div[data-id='"+divs[i]+"']").css("color", "red");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list">
 <div data-id="2741">Hola</div>
 <div data-id="1499">Hola</div>
 <div data-id="5732">Hola</div>
 <div data-id="6372">Mundo</div>
 <div data-id="1034">Mundo</div>
</div>
```

Comment: So happy that it helps you!